# WebSockets are not working in @microsoft/signalr

Tags: signalr, signalr.client, azure-signalr

I Have configured the signalr with ASP NET core. When i use local service, it works properly. When i use after host it's not working as expected throws the below error.

[image]

Here is the code that i have done.

```
import * as signalR from '@microsoft/signalr';
const connection: signalR.HubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('wss://demo/staging/web-services/hubs/spreadsheethub',
{
   skipNegotiation: true,
   transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets, 
}).build();
...
});
connection.on('dataReceived', (data: string) => {
 // code
 });
connection.start().then(() => {
    console.log('server connected!!!');
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Are websocket connections allowed on your host? What kind of hosting do you use?

Comment: AWS hosting services

Comment: I am not sure about that specific host, but usually you have to explicitly set the server to allow websocket connections, and they are disabled by default.